# How to retrieve the image of an RSS Feed?

Tags: javascript, xml, image, rss, feed

I created a JS code, but cannot retrieve the url of the images from my RSS Feed.

How to retrieve the image of an RSS Feed ?

const FEED_URL = `https://www.s1biose.com/fr/test/rss.xml`;

```
fetch(FEED_URL)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
  .then(data => {
    const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
    let html = ``;
    items.forEach(el => {
      html += `
        <div class="card mb-3 text-start position-relative text-dark">
          <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="${el.querySelector("enclosure").innerHTML}" alt="${el.querySelector("title").innerHTML}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title h5">${el.querySelector("title").innerHTML}</div>
                <p class="card-text">${el.querySelector("description").innerHTML}</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">${el.querySelector("pubDate").innerHTML}</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="${el.querySelector("link").innerHTML}" title="${el.querySelector("title").innerHTML}" class="stretched-link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
        </div>
      `;
    });
    document.querySelector('#feed').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  });
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see as `src` in rendered version in your dev tools inspector?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't see anything, no url. Here is the site mathieulebert.fr it is about the Feed RSS at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Simple fix. Look at the xml . You need the `url` attribute of `<enclosure url="..."`

Comment: @charlietfl The url must be automatically retrieved by JS. Can you reply with the correct code? Because in your comment you indicate the url manually.

Comment: Try `el.querySelector("enclosure").getAttribute('url')`

Comment: @charlietfl It works, thanks.

Comment: Bienvenue! .....